# I can not install freeminer

Tags: apt

When I follow all the steps it says.

```
comp123@comp123-ThinkCentre-M71e:~$  sudo apt-get install freeminer
[sudo] password for comp123: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  freeminer-data
Suggested packages:
  freeminer-server freeminer-mod-moreblocks freeminer-mod-moreores
  freeminer-mod-pipeworks
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  freeminer freeminer-data
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 7,292 kB of archives.
After this operation, 22.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Ign:1 http://screenshots.getdeb.net xenial-getdeb/games i386 freeminer-data all 0.4.14.8-1~getdeb1
Err:2 http://screenshots.getdeb.net xenial-getdeb/games amd64 freeminer amd64 0.4.14.8-1~getdeb1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2400:cb00:2048:1::681c:197d 80]
Err:1 http://screenshots.getdeb.net xenial-getdeb/games i386 freeminer-data all 0.4.14.8-1~getdeb1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2400:cb00:2048:1::681c:197d 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://screenshots.getdeb.net/pool/games/f/freeminer/freeminer-data_0.4.14.8-1~getdeb1_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2400:cb00:2048:1::681c:197d 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://screenshots.getdeb.net/pool/games/f/freeminer/freeminer_0.4.14.8-1~getdeb1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 2400:cb00:2048:1::681c:197d 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, try running apt-get update or apt-get --fix-missing.
```

I can ran update and fix missing but nothing worked

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04...

Answer (score 0):

So, I've  just tested this on my PC. Yours is trying to download from their xenial- archive but mine is trying to grab it from the zesty- archive despite both of us using 16.04.

Try removing your current apt sources and re-adding theirs.

Go to System Settings > Software and Updates > Untick the archive.getdeb repository.
[image: getdeb repo]

(mine says Zesty but yours will say Xenial)

Then try to add the new repository:

```
wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu zesty-getdeb games" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'
```

Comment: Does not work :(

Comment: Did you get the same error?

Comment: Yes I did......

Comment: Could you add it to your question for me? I need to know if it still says Xenial or not :)

Comment: Never mind I installed it from the get Deb site and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I installed it from the deb package and it worked